# Is there any difference using TimeDistributed on single Dense Layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Is there any difference between adding a TimeDistributed wrapper around a single Dense layer? Both have the same number of parameters (2,208) and same output shape of (None, 6, 32). The purpose is I have a sequence of data that is 6 time steps long with each time step having 64 features that I want to pass through a Dense layer.

```
# With TimeDistributed
m = keras.models.Sequential()
m.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'), input_shape=(6, 64)))

# No TimeDistributed
m = keras.models.Sequential()
m.add(keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(6, 64)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no difference between the 2 examples.

By default if `len(input_shape) = 2` for the `Dense` layer (excluding the batch dimension) then it behaves in the same way like using `TimeDistributed` layer.

However, if you flatten (`Flatten` layer) your input and then feed it into a `Dense` layer then it is a different story.